# floats with overflow hidden and min-width in firefox

Tags: css, css-float

I am working on a simple responsive layout, where I have a list containing of an small floated left image and information about image on side . On full width, I want to display info on same row as image. On small width I need the text to appear under image. I am using min-width in info container along with overflow hidden, so it does not wrap. This works in chrome but not in firefox. Is there any workaround? Thank you.

code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image">

            </div>
            <div class="info">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">

            </div>
            <div class="info">

            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image">

            </div>
            <div class="info">

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {width:100%}
.image {height:50px;width:50px;margin:10px;border:1px solid;float:left}
.info {min-width:200px;overflow:hidden}
.clear {clear:both}
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/b4ffoayh/

Solution: what works for me - I added float left to .info as well and put 70%width on .info. This way firefox seems to cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries. Here's a fast example based off of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/b4ffoayh/1/

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .image {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Shrink the html window to see it working.

I also added the clear on the lists to fix the floating issues. Overflow:hidden is not necessary unless you're really wanting it for some reason.

Comment: I do not want to use mediaqueries. Think of wrapper as only a part of full width. So I need to do this based on width of wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Both elements within the list-item need to be floating. Then the .info needs to take up remaining space next to the image, which can be achieved by using the calc() function.

This is what I added to make it work:

```
.info {float:left;width:calc(100% - 100px);}
li:after {content:" ";display:block;clear:left;}
```

Comment: hi, I think I need a solution for css2 as well:)